# Handle transactions with BMT

Tags: hibernate, ejb, java-ee-6, jta, bean-managed-transactions

I'm working on a legacy project that make use of EJB 3.2 + Hibernate .
The entities has properties like 'status' and also have and 'id' and a 'version'.
Every service bean is BMT managed and I have to add an 'edit' feature that takes an entity id as input and do the following steps:

1. find the entity A by id, change its status to disabled and save it on db.
2. create a new entity B which is the previous one but with status changed to ACTIVE , the same ID and the VERSION = the previous version + 1

so I have to mantain an history of the edited ones managing the version property and status

I'm struggling to manage all in the same BMT transaction boundaries , because in my mind this should be managed in a single transaction but since inner transaction is not allowed in BMT I  can't find a proper solution. For example , I can't update the same reference to the entity more than one time : the first time when saving the old entity changing the status to disabled, and the other one with version + 1.

example:

```
public ScheduleInfoDto update(ScheduleInfoDto resource) throws MB3BfException {
    try {
        ut.begin(); // **


        // disable previous entity
        ScheduleInfoIdDto oldId = resource.getId();
        ScheduleInfoDto scheduleInfo = getRepository().find(oldId);
        scheduleInfo.setStatus(ExecutionStatus.DISABLED);
        scheduleInfo.setLast(LastVersion.NO);
        scheduleInfoRepository.update(scheduleInfo);

        // save the new entity changing the version and the status
        scheduleInfo.getId().setVersion(scheduleInfo.getId().getVersion()+1);
        scheduleInfo.setStatus(ExecutionStatus.ACTIVE);
        scheduleInfo.setLast(LastVersion.YES);
        ut.commit(); // **

    } catch (..) {
}
```

what is the best practice to hadle this kind of situation ?

since I'm forced to use BMT for the related service, I'm wondering if it's a good practice to create a new transaction for each peace of code in order to have flushed on db the modifications.
Something like :

```
public ScheduleInfoDto update(ScheduleInfoDto resource) throws MB3BfException {
    try {

        ut.begin(); // *
        // disable previous entity
        ScheduleInfoIdDto oldId = resource.getId();
        ScheduleInfoDto scheduleInfo = getRepository().find(oldId);
        scheduleInfo.setStatus(ExecutionStatus.DISABLED);
        scheduleInfo.setLast(LastVersion.NO);
        scheduleInfoRepository.update(scheduleInfo);
        ut.commit(); // *

        ut.begin(); // **
        // save the new entity changing the version and the status
        scheduleInfo.getId().setVersion(scheduleInfo.getId().getVersion()+1);
        scheduleInfo.setStatus(ExecutionStatus.ACTIVE);
        scheduleInfo.setLast(LastVersion.YES);
        ut.commit(); // **

    } catch (..) {
}
```

thanks in advice